# Open multiple Excel files in separate instances with batch file

Tags: windows, excel, batch-file, application-restart, vba

I run multiple Excel instances / files which require a manual PC restart daily. Currently I save all my Excels, restart the PC, then have to open each file separately, which is quite manual. Is anyone aware of a program I can run that will open the same Excel files in separate Excel instances after reboot?

### Solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "excel=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\Excel.exe"
for %%a in (
 "R:\Other Stuff\Name\text_excel_1.xlsx"
 "R:\Other Stuff\Name\text_excel_2.xlsx"
) do start "" "%excel%" "%%~a"
```

### Previous Edits:

I've gotten this far with a batch BUT the second Excel instance won't open unless I close the first.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\Excel.exe"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\Excel.exe"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\Excel.exe"
```

Has anyone see this before?

***EDIT:*** have tried using the `start` command, but this opens the both files in the same instance. How would I go about opening them in multiple instances?

```
start /d "R:\Other Stuff\Name" test_excel_1.xlsx
start /d "R:\Other Stuff\Name" test_excel_1.xlsx
```

***EDIT 2:***

R is a share drive; this opens multiple Excel instances but can't find the files. Do I need to modify for network drives? But I was able to open them using the `start /d` command which is a tad puzzling for me.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "excel=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\Excel.exe"
for %%a in (
 "R:\Other Stuff\Name\text_excel_1.xlsx"
 "R:\Other Stuff\Name\text_excel_2.xlsx"
) do start "" "%excel%" "%%~a"
```

Error is now:

> 'R:\Other Stuff\Name\test_excel_2.xlsx' cannot be found. Checking spelling or try a different path.

Does anyone see anything wrong with this? `start /d` finds the file but the code starting with `@echo off` does not find the file.

Comment: How are you launching the batch file? Double-click from Explorer? From command line? From scheduled job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to open all `xlsx` files in current folder with excel:

```
for %%a in (*.xlsx) do start "" "%%a"
```

(for use on command line, replace every `%%a` with `%a`)

To open every file in a separate EXCEL instance:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "excel=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE"
for %%a in (
 "R:\Other Stuff\Name\Document1.xls"
 "C:\users\JSNoob\documents\my Passwords.xlsx"
) do start "" "%excel%" "%%~a"
```

(adapt the excel path to fit your system and add the files, you need)

Comment: not quite what I'm after. I've done some research and have found I should start command

      start /d "R:\Other Stuff\Name" test_excel_1.xlsx
      start /d "R:\Other Stuff\Name" test_excel_1.xlsx

Comment: how about now ?

Comment: How would I adopt this if I knew the path of each file? The folder contains multiple files I do not need

Comment: VERY close! I've now open multiple excel instances but now I can't find the files... Does it work differently if the path is a network drive?

Comment: nope - I tested it with a network drive: working fine here.

Comment: Very weird, thank you for your help... Can't shake this error though